# I seem not to get it right in regex in python when matching digits

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a list containing items that mirror file names. I would like to filter only the names that are contain only digits. I seem not to get it right. Even matching a a single digit seem not to be working. Am I the one not doing it right? Any leads or suggestions would be appreciated.

Sample of code:

```
import re

pattern = r"^\d.+[.]"
pattern2 = r'\d*'

a = ["1000.mp4", "test.mp4", "110082.mp4", "829873.m4a"]

for i in a:
    if re.match(i, pattern):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Pattern should be the first argument to `re.match`. See `help(re.match)` for more info.

Comment: You don't need regex. Python string has `isdigit()`. You just need to check filename without extension

Comment: Also, `re.match` already matches from start of the input. The naming is bad for this method, so I always use `re.search` with anchors instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working code. You can fiddle around the regex to get a better regex string for matching without dot character.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"^[0-9]+.")

a = ["1000.mp4", "test.mp4", "110082.mp4", "829873.m4a"]

for i in a:
    match = re.match(pattern, i)
    if match:
        matched_string = match.group(0)
        string_without_dot = matched_string[0:len(matched_string)-1]
        print(string_without_dot)
```

Comment: This one capture both .mp4 and m4a

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

pattern = r"\d+?.\w+"

Or, if you want to capture the file name:

pattern = r"(\d+?).\w+"

But this will not work if your filename contains ".".

Comment: I did quick list comprehension but It seem to capture the matches                                   
 ``` a = ["1000.mp4", "test.mp4", "110082.mp4", "829873.m4a"]
pattern = r"\d+?.\w+"
fin = [j for j in a if re.match(j, pattern)]
print(fin) ```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have mistaken the argument order of the `re.match` function.

Here is a code that I have tested and does what you require:

```py
# Regex explanation,
# ^ Indicates position at start of a line.
# \d+ Indicates any digit and can be N number of times. Digit is defined as [0-9].
# \. Indicates a literal .
# \w+ Indicates any word and can be N number of times. Word is defined as [a-zA-Z0-9_].
pattern = r'^\d+\.\w+'

files_list = ["1000.mp4", "test.mp4", "110082.mp4", "829873.m4a"]

for file in files_list:
    # The order of arguments for re.match should be, (pattern, string).
    if re.match(pattern, file):
        print(file)
```

Output:

```
1000.mp4
110082.mp4
829873.m4a
```

Comment: How about the .m4a?

Comment: @Moses I have adjusted my answer, I missed that out.

Comment: Works perfectly well. It captures all the extensions!!!

Comment: Helped delete over 10000 files with a single command in subdirectories. This has proved helpful.

Comment: I am delighted that it helped you to accomplish your task.